# Reading floating point numbers from text file and copying to a vector of floating point numbers

Tags: c++, vector, text-files

I need to make a code in c++ that reads **floating point numbers** from a text file separated by **commas** and copies to a vector of **floating point numbers**.The text file contains several thousands of floating point integers seperated by a comma ( like 1, 1, 69.8, 110, 0, -1.8, -1.8, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.23,).I tried using **getline()**, but i guess it is meant to read text file as strings, and save in a vector of strings , not floating point numbers.Can any one help me with this

The following code is not working in the way i expected

```
vector<float> ReplayBuffer;
ifstream in;
in.open("fileName.txt");
if(in.is_open())
{
    in.setf(ios::fixed);
    in.precision(3);

   in.seekg(0,ios::end);
   fileSizes = in.tellg();

   in.seekg(0,ios::beg);
   float number = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<fileSizes/sizeof(float);i++)
   {
    getline(in, ReplayBuffer[i],', ');
   }

   for(int i = 0;i<ReplayBuffer.size();i++)
    {  cout<<ReplayBuffer[i]<<" , "<<endl; }
   in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read floats directly from the input stream: `in >> ReplayBuffer". You need to take care to skip the commas.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language, so don't tag it C if it is hasn't got anything to do with C.

Comment: Correction. You don't have floating-point numbers in the file. You have decimal numbers in ASCII format with fractional parts. You need to *convert* them to floating-point.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is perhaps

```
for (std::string f; getline(in, f, ',');)
  ReplayBuffer.push_back(std::stof(f));
```

You'll need to wrap it in a `try` - `catch` block if there's any chance the floats in the file are invalid.

Your code can then be simplified to something like

```
vector<float> ReplayBuffer;
ifstream in("fileName.txt");

for (std::string f; getline(in, f, ',');)
  ReplayBuffer.push_back(std::stof(f));

for (auto f : ReplayBuffer)
  std::cout << f << " , ";
```

`fixed` and `precision` only affects output (unless you are using a custom `num_get` facet), even if you were to keep your original code those two lines do nothing.

Comment: The suggested code, doesnt seem to work.Show the error 

error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided

Comment: @sarath either you haven't included `string` or your compiler doesn't support the string overloads of [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), which is unlikely.